# rake spec fails where rake spec:(models|controllers|views) pass

Tags: rspec, ruby-1.9.2, ruby-on-rails-2

I asked this question on the rspec mailing list but didn't get a response, so I thought I'd try here.

Using rspec 1.3.2 and rspec-rails 1.3.4 with rails 2.3.11 on ruby 1.9.2-p180, when I

```
$ rake spec:models
```

they all pass. When I

```
$ rake spec:controllers
```

they all pass. When I

```
$ rake spec:views
```

they all pass. But when I

```
$ rake spec
```

I get

`<path to gem>/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:177: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)`

I've been tinkering around with the rake file, and when I change

`t.spec_files = FileList['spec/**/*_spec.rb']`

in the default task to hit just one of the subdirectories, such as

`t.spec_files = FileList['spec/models/**/*_spec.rb']`

then rake spec works. I've done this for models, controllers, and views, and rake spec works fine for each. But including all of them like

`t.spec_files = FileList['spec/models/**/*_spec.rb', 'spec/controllers/**/*_spec.rb', 'spec/views/**/*_spec.rb']`

does **not** work (same error as mentioned above). Ironically, including just models and views does work:

`t.spec_files = FileList['spec/models/**/*_spec.rb', 'spec/views/**/*_spec.rb']`

but it seems that any combination including controllers will fail. This is odd to me since rake spec:controllers works. Unless it has something to do with the number of files and/or examples. The number of files and examples for each spec type is

```
models:      25 files, 391 examples
controllers: 26 files, 973 examples
views:       52 files, 508 examples
```

Using just rake spec did work on Ruby 1.8.7(-p302) and Ruby 1.9.1(-p243).

Does anyone have any ideas? I can run each group individually (and even create an alias to do it all at once), but then rspec has to spin up the app 3 times. Besides, that doesn't address why this isn't working on ruby 1.9.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't explain why, but when I remove

```
--loadby mtime
--reverse
```

from spec/spec.opts, rake spec works again. It *might* have something to do with this thread [1], but I don't know.

Peace.

[1] http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1151108